# Installing openSSL on easyphp for developing an facebook app

Tags: apache, ssl, https, openssl, easyphp

I've been trying to develop a facebook app. But since 1 oct 2012 facebook needs secured (https /  SSL) connections.  before i start the real app and get a server with SSL i really want to test creating an facebook app.

So i foun openSSL and thought i might install that on my easyphp (apache)  local server.

Only problem is that its a bit tricky to find out how to. I'm no server/apache/ssl pro. i create web apps. So is there anyone who has some info on how to do this.

Or maybe other (better) suggestions of going at it.

thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a way to test building an facebook app without needing a server with SSL.
Just use a public dropbox link. Dropbox is secured.
The simple tutorial can be found here:
http://www.wpcode.net/fb-app-dropbox.html/
I have to add one thing though. Facebook requires a folder instead of a file. To cheat this add yourfile.html?fakevar=1 to your dropbox public link.
p.s. dropbox cant parse php/asp so its just for js and basic testing.
I hope this saves someone some time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Though it is too late to answer but Using Open SSL in facebook app is not a good idea . There are many cheap SSL there you can buy one of them . For Example I bought Positive SSL ( only for one domain or on sub-domain ) for 9$ .

You Try [Heroku](http://heroku.com/) to deploy and test your app